# Selecting equal fields from two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to select fields "session_id" with the same value from two tables.
My query is the following

```
SELECT landingpages1988.session_id 
FROM [30032015.landingpages1988], [30032015.exitpages1988] 
WHERE 30032015.landingpages1988.session_id=30032015.exitpages1988.session_id
```

I get this error:

> Error: Encountered "" at line 3, column 44

Could you please assist in correcting?

Comment: What's the purpose of this query? What are you trying to do, explain in words?

Comment: @Pentium10, I have two tables. 1st one landingpages1988 contains the following data: session id, landing page name, pageviews. 2nd table: session id, exit page name, pageviews.

I need to analyze what % of the landing pages visits relulted in session breaks. As I understand, I would need to find the sessions, where landing page was the exit page. So My query is to find the matching session id's from table landingpages1988 and exitpages1988

Comment: See my update. You can use that syntax with counts also.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator in FROM line it means union, and not join.

You could run something like:

```
SELECT t1.select_column
FROM [table1] t1
join [table2] t2
join each on t1.join_column=t2.join_column
WHERE t1.equal_column=t2.equal_column
```

**Update**

```
 SELECT session_id
FROM [30032015.landingpages1988]
WHERE session_id NOT IN (SELECT session_id FROM [30032015.exitpages1988])
```

Comment: nope, still an error:
Error: Encountered "" at line 3, column 44.

Comment: @ArtemRisukhin check now

Comment: thanks, I tried the updated version of the code. It worked, yet the result is the following:
Query returned zero records.

I just don't understand the updated query - the operation done. Could you please specify? Thanks